# Set initial time ahead of TimeOfDay.now() in showTimePicker

Tags: android, flutter, dart, time

This may be a very silly question. But I don't know how to achieve this. How to set the `initial time` of `showTimePicker` ahead of `TimeOfDay.now()` in `Flutter`. Let's say 3 hours ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
            GestureDetector(
    onTap: () async {
        TimeOfDay picked = await showTimePicker(
        context: context,
        initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours:3))),
        builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
           return MediaQuery(
           data: MediaQuery.of(context)
           .copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
           child: child,
           );
        },);
     },
     child: Text("SetTime",textAlign: TextAlign.center,))
```

Use the [`fromDateTime`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TimeOfDay/TimeOfDay.fromDateTime.html), constructor of class `TimeOfDay`, and then call the `DateTime.now()` and use the `add()` method to create a `Duration` 3 hours from now.